# Retriving lost VB 6 component license keys

Tags: vb6, licensing, license-key

HI

I'm moving a visual basic 6 application from one machine to another, however this application is quite old and uses a lot of third party components (.ocx files) that we have lost the license key for.

Is there any way to get the license key off the old machine for use on the new machine?

Once the application can be built on the new machine, the old machine will be decommissioned and all data erased.

Comment: Did you try transferring `HKCR\Licenses` from old machine?

Comment: I haven't tried that.  Is that were the licenses for visual basic components are usualy kept?

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it didnt work.

Comment: Vb6 OCX's and dlls often had accompanying LIC files (often in the \windows\system32 or system folders, usually in the same folder as the installed OCX/DLL). if you copy that file, you should be good.

Comment: But note, some OCX's/dlls used different licensing techniques, putting stuff in the registry, or putting stuff in other files, or requiring the code to call a function to "register" the library before use, so it'll all depend on the libraries in question.

Comment: Ok thanks for those comments. I'd like to give drventure the tick but I don't see how thats possible unless you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep my VB6 dev kit in a VM image for this sort of reason - getting a working development state can be a hard-fought battle for VB6 stuff, but it also has the tendency to soil it's own house by filling it with left-over bits of dead COM components. So if I install new tools or components, I do it in the base snapshot, then restore any required bits into a new snapshot for that project.

Not really a helpful answer for your current predicament... but hopefully helpful for long-term legacy VB6 maintenance.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I don't have working snap-shot I can just transfer to another machine but anyway thats good advice.